# SQL Server 2008 Find row based on 1 unique column and duplicates in a second column

Tags: sql-server

Can you please suggest how I can write a query to retrieve the following?

I need to find any rows where the value in A is duplicated but the value in B is different

```
  A    B 
4567    2 
852125  9
444     8
2547    25
255     4
256     1
2547    25
2547    27
259     4
2547    25
```

Should return

```
2547    27 
2547    25
```

As 2547 has two non identical values in column B

Thanks in anticipation

P

Comment: `SELECT a, b, count(b) as cnt from your table group by b having cnt<>1`?

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte1 as (
    select distinct A, B from Table1
), cte2 as (
    select A, B, count(*) over(partition by A) as cnt from cte1
)
select
    A, B
from cte2 
where cnt > 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76098/4)</kbd>**

or

```
with cte as (
    select distinct
        A, B, min(B) over(partition by A) as m1, max(B) over(partition by A) as m2
    from Table1
)
select
    A, B
from cte
where m1 <> m2
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76098/3)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
With DemoTable  AS
(
          Select 4567   A,2  B
Union All Select 852125  ,9
Union All Select 444     ,8
Union All Select 2547    ,25
Union All Select 255     ,4
Union All Select 256     ,1
Union All Select 2547    ,25
Union All Select 2547    ,27
Union All Select 259     ,4
Union All Select 2547    ,25
)
Select Distinct A, B
From DemoTable  
Where A In
(
    Select A
    From DemoTable
    Group By A
    Having Count (Distinct B) > 1
)
```

Output

```
A           B
----------- -----------
2547        25
2547        27

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thank you but the tabloe is 20000 entries long!

Answer (score 1):

it's simple just use a **nested** select statement which one of them has **count**, **group by** and **having** statements.

```
select distinct tbl.A,tbl.B from table_name tbl
 where tbl.A in (select A from (
  select  tb.A, count(tb.B) 
  from table_name tb group by tb.A having count(tb.B)>1)) 
order by tbl.A
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Code only answers are usually not very useful unless they explain what they do.  Please consider adding an explanation of what you changed or wrote.

Comment: Hello and thanks for annotation, After this I'll do that; the code only was because of time limitation

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this code several ways but keep getting a syntax error